# how to change a background of google vr full screen icon in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, magento, google-vr

```
function onVrViewLoad() {
   var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
      image: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/<?php echo $value['image_path']  ?>',
      width:'500px',
      height:'300px'
    });
}
```

Comment: please help me immediately

Comment: Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  And then maybe you might get some help.

Comment: That is `img` tag getting created with class `img.webvr-button`

Comment: img.webvr-button is not working bro